# How to handle loc-key in remote Push Notification payload

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've implemented handling of remote push notifications in  `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in AppDelegate.swift and it works except for payloads of following format.

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
        "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "This is Message"]
    },
    "sound" : "chime.aiff"
},
"acme" : "foo"
}
```

I want to format and show the content of loc-args on the notification alert. I want to extract "Jenna" and "This is Message" from loc-args and display on alert as below in body and title of alert:

**New Message from Jenna**

**This is message**

I've been reading tuts but I can't figure out what exactly I've to do to get it done. I want to keep it simple. Any help?
Tx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution was Localizable.strings